# SCOTT Scale 710 Tires

Tags: mountain-bike

I purchased a SCOTT Scale 710 Plus Bike yesterday.  For some reasons,  I am not going to stick with a plus tire. I plan to replace the current tires to smaller ones (maybe the 27.5x2.35). I do not know if it is possible. Will doing this cause any issue to the bike? Do I need to change the rims, hubs, etc.?
Someone please let me know! Thank you very much indeed!
Alex

Comment: You just bought it yesterday and you've already decided not to stick with plus tires?  Does the store have a return policy?

Comment: How wide is the rim?  What size tyre is on it now ?   I'd explore returning the bike and you buy what you really want.

Comment: What @Kibbee said. Scott Scale comes in 27, 27plus and 29er, with about 100 models in various prices. Can't understand why you would buy a new one that was not exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

No it would not cause any technical issue to the bike. How well it handles can only be determined by experimenting.

However:

The 27.5+ tyre has a similar diameter to a 29 tyre. If you want to maintain the geometry and handling of a bike move to 29.

Either way moving to a 27.5 or 29 will require a new wheel set. The plus rims are too wide for a standard tyre, although it may work it would give the tyre a bad shape. You could reuse the hubs you have which would save you money but that would make the conversion back more difficult. But you'd only have to buy rims. In NZ I'd say about 40%the cost of a wheel set comes from the hubs ($800 for a wheelset, $200 for rims, $100 for spokes, $200 for labour and $300 for hubs). Unfortunately boost hubs and the xd driver will be at the steeper end of the market.

Then you'd need tyres on top of that.

If you'd want to retain interchangeability you'd need a new wheelset, rotors, cassette and tyres. Then you'd have options.

Not sure why you're planning to move away from 27.5+, nothing suggest any benefits of 27.5 over 27.5+.

Comment: I definitely loved how the bike is designed, that was why I bought it. However, the bike itself came with plus tires. So I decided to change the tire's size

Comment: *nothing suggest any benefits of 27.5 over 27.5+*, well, rotational weight for one